# Node.js memcached with unix socket /var/run/memcached/memcached.sock

Tags: node.js, memcached, unix-socket

Node.js don't connecting to **memcached** server by using `unix socket`

> /var/run/memcached/memcached.sock

I'm using this example code to connect memcached server

```
var Memcached = require('memcached');

var mem = new Memcached('/var/run/memcached/memcached.sock');

mem.set('ping', 'Hello World', 60, function (err) {
    if (!err)
        mem.get('ping', function (err, data) {
            if (!err)
                console.log(data);
        });
});
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js MemCached `unix socket` bug fixed [here](https://github.com/ChandraNakka/memcached).

Just use this command line to install working version

```
npm install git+https://git@github.com/ChandraNakka/memcached.git --save
```

Comment: You should post a pull request, because otherwise It will be a pain to do it everytime you wish to update, or if you're installing your app in other server.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande they are rejected by pull request with no reason. That's why I'm writing this post

Comment: Never said you shouldn't answer :), then you should probably use a fork on your project.

Comment: Yes bro, I'm already forked with this patch. But, this post for upcoming people to save their time from this bug. I'm already wasted upto 3 hours to find out this bug.